# why we not make array of size max of my computer memory?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```cpp
#nclude <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main int()
{
    size_t max_value = (size_t)-1;
    cout << max_value << endl;

    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (max_value));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < max_value;i++)
    {
        cout << ptr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "done"<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

`int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (max_value));` why does the code get killed on this line?

Can you explain what's happing in this code?

Comment: `max_value` is the largest possible size value. Now you want to compute 4 times the largest possible value. What would that be?!

Comment: Did you verify `malloc` can return 'null' ?

Comment: Even without `* sizeof(int)`, your array isn't the only thing occupying the memory. And assuming a 64-bit app, it's physically impossible to have so much RAM installed.

Comment: Your code has several typos, can you please [edit] your post and copy & paste the code you've verified to produce the error you claim into it (`int main int()` is plain nonsense, `#nclude` is missing an 'i', ...)

Comment: [`std::malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) "On failure, returns a null pointer." Why did you expect "the code get killed" ?

Comment: Assuming a 64-bit `size_t`, that would be over 70 *million* terabytes. Also, assuming one microsecond per loop iteration (pretty fast for an output loop), your program would run for more than half a million years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` is the largest number a `size_t` can express. Measured in bytes, it is 18,446,744 **terabytes**. I am going to assume your system does not have that much memory.

Multiplying this number by `sizeof(int)` does not make this number four times bigger (it is impossible). Instead, the bit pattern inside gets shifted to the left by two places, which has the net effect of subtracting 3 from `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.